# Constant in Complexity of SQRT algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, landau-notation

this is my first question in CS so I apologize if this question is off-topic.

If we use Newton`s Method for finding square root then complexity is $O(M(n))$ (using Wikipedia Notation: $M(n)$ is the algorithm to multiply two $n$-digit numbers).

I am interested to know whats the constant hidden in Landau notation in this case and/or how can I calculate it.

Comment: What's $n$?  Is it the number of bits of precision that you want the answer to have?

Comment: I would imagine that $n$ is [[the bit-length of the input] plus [the number of bits after $\hspace{1.4 in}$ the binary point that you want the answer of have]]. $\:$